# mongoose findByIdAndRemove doesn't work as expected

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my API I have route

```
router.delete('/remove', auth(), e2Controller.remove);
```

remove method use findOneAndRemove from mongoose API

```
const E2 = require('../models/e2.model');
exports.remove = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log('ID IS...................', req.query.id);
        E2.findByIdAndRemove(req.query.id);
        res.json({ message: 'OK' })
    } catch (e) {
        return next(e);
    }
};
```

I'm calling this endpoint with postman and I have message: ok json in response but then I look into my DB and it is not removed.

In console I see correct id:

> ID IS................... 5d220cf9c8fe162c54fc4e5d
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2019:19:36:27 +0000] "DELETE /api/e2/remove?id=5d220cf9c8fe162c54fc4e5d HTTP/1.1" 200 16 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.1.1"

Why it doesn't delete it from collection??

[image]

Comment: You have an `async` function should there not be an `await` in front of your db/mongoose query?

Comment: omg.................... of course, post it as answer so i can accept and u earn some points

Comment: also maybe do something (I do) like `const doc=await  etc..` then you should get the document that was deleted returned (and you can log that to check).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `async` function should there not be an `await` in front of your db/mongoose query?

also maybe do something (I do) like `const doc=await  etc..` then you should get the document that was deleted returned (and you can log that to check).